# VBA - .Sort Method turns data into TRUE

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm trying to do something pretty usual : sort two related ranges in the ascending order of just one of those.

I have a range starting on cell A3 with a variable length, and another on cell B3 with a variable length (supposedly equal)

```
With Worksheets(SheetName)
Set range1 = .Range("A3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown))
Set range2 = .Range("B3", .Range("B3").End(xlDown))
End With

Range(range1 , range2) = Range(range1 , range2).Sort(Key1:=range1, Order1:=xlAscending)
```

My code seems pretty innocent but instead of sorting the data, it declares every value as a TRUE Boolean. I have no idea why this happens.

My whole module worked fine before I tried implementing the automatic sorting, so I'd rather not change too much my variables and variable types.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`Range(range1 , range2) = Range(range1 , range2).Sort(Key1:=range1, Order1:=xlAscending)`

do

`Range(range1 , range2).Sort Key1:=range1, Order1:=xlAscending`

The sorting of range happens in place. So, you dont have to re-assign the values of `Sort` to the original range.

Comment: ++You beat me to it :D. I was testing the code. When I came back to post, saw your answer... LMAO

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it !